# Checkboxes em AlertDialog sempre retornam os mesmos valores

Tags: android, checkbox, alertdialog

Tenho um `AlertDialog` com um layout personalizado com 2 checkboxes. Mas, mesmo que eu clique numa dessas checkboxes, ao clicar nos botões de aceitar ou cancelar (`alert.setPositiveButton` ou o `alert.setNegativeButton`), recebo os valores padrão das checkboxes e não sei se cliquei nelas ou não.

**Criação do AlertDialog**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(novo_layout.this);
alert.setCancelable(false);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
alert.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_alert, null));
alert.setMessage(IdAsString);
```

**Variáveis das checkboxes**

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_alert, null);
sentado = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.sentado);
livre = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.livre);
```

**Verificação das checkboxes**

```
alert.setPositiveButton("X", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

    if(!sentado.isChecked()&&!livre.isChecked()){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Os dados não foram gravados, indroduza uma posição", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     //checkBoxClicked.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Sempre que faz a verificação `if(!sentado.isChecked()&&!livre.isChecked())` retorna verdadeiro (por padrão, nenhuma checkbox está clicada), mesmo que eu tenha clicado numa checkbox.

Comment: Veja assim:   if (!sentado.isChecked()) && (!livre.isChecked()) {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está em que as variáveis `sentado` e `livre` referem-se aos CheckBox de outra View e não àquela passada ao *AlertDialog*.

```
alert.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_alert, null));
```

No código anterior é "inflada" uma *View* e passada ao *AlertDialog*.

Depois, com

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_alert, null);
sentado = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.sentado);
livre = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.livre);
```

está a "inflar" outra *View* para obter as referências aos *CheckBox*.

O que deve ser feito é passar a *View*, usada para obter as referências, ao *AlertDialog*.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_alert, null);
sentado = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.sentado);
livre = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.livre);

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(novo_layout.this);
alert.setCancelable(false);
alert.setView(view);
alert.setMessage(IdAsString);
```

Comment: Exatamente! Muito mais facil de entender, obrigado

Comment: Uma dúvida que me surgiu agora ao completar o meu codigo, quando eu tiver 5 `checkboxes` selecionadas, e quisser desselecionar-las eu só vou conseguir aceder ao valores das `checkboxes` sentado e livre da ultima checkbox selecionada. Como e que eu posso resolver esta situação? 
Se for preciso posso editar o código de modo a ficar mais claro, @ramaral

Comment: Tente explicar melhor pois não percebi o que quer dizer com: "só vou conseguir aceder ao valores das checkboxes sentado e livre da ultima checkbox selecionada".

Comment: Já editei o código e acho que já está melhor explicado @ramaral

Comment: Isso é outro problema, é melhor você abrir outra pergunta.